# How to CheckStyle a specific string in a filetype

Tags: cucumber, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am currently figuring out a way on how to add a **CheckStyle** for Cucumber's Feature file.
Tried searching but I couldn't find an answer.

Essentially what I want to accomplish is

1. Search for a tag/string called `@develop` for every `.feature` file.
2. If this **tag** is found, return the **CheckStyle** error.

As of now what I have is ( doesn't work ):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"  "http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="feature"/>
    <module name="RegexpSingleline">
        <property name="format" value="@develop"/>
        <property name="minimum" value="0"/>
        <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
        <property name="message" value="Line has a @develop tag."/>
    </module>
</module>
```

When I tried :

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="Regexp">
        <property name="format" value="(@develop)"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

IntelliJ stated I can't add RegEx under Checker.

Here's my POM for the CheckStyle plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipStaticAnalysis}</skip>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <configLocation>build_config/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <propertyExpansion>basedir=${project.basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                    <violationSeverity>info</violationSeverity>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please provide more details, such as the exact maven command you are using, and the relevant maven output (reflecting failure). Your first configuration IS correct, and will provide the expected results if your POM is configured correctly.

Comment: I use IntelliJ's built-in feature when I do active development. IntelliJ has a check style module that you could use. But also when I try to do a `mvn clean compile` it doesn't throw any warning.

Comment: It appears you have bound Checkstyle execution to the `verify` phase, you should be able to run `mvn verify` to initiate Checkstyle execution.